# Dynamic nested list : insert line on click, after current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with a list that can be drag/dropped and nested.

How it should work :
1.Each row has an "add line" button. 
2.When this button is clicked, I am trying to insert a new line, which is a text box, directly below/after the element where the button was clicked 
3.Then get/add a unique ID for the new element/row. 
4.Lastly once typing text in the new elements text box, get this text (to post to server).

The Javascript looks like this now :

$(document).on('click', '#addLabel_Item', function () {

```
    var tree_id = ($(this).prop("title"));
    var $tree_box = '#' + tree_id;
    var $tree_box_item = '#' + tree_id + ' li';

    var currentListItem = $(this).closest(".listed").attr("id");
    var $items=$('.listed');
    var parentID = $items.index($(this).closest(".listed"));

    $("#list_reference_2").show();
    //$("#list_reference_2").clone(true).insertAfter($("li").closest("ol#top_list_items li:eq(" + parentID + ")"));
    //$("#list_reference_2").clone().insertAfter('ol > li:nth-child(1)');
    $("#list_reference_2").clone().insertAfter("ol li:eq(" + parentID + ")");


});
```

Right now if I click to add a new line, it adds to the proper place on the initial/first click on the button. However, subsequent clicking on a different button adds the lines under the initial/first row rather than under the current one just clicked.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesstern/tx7hbkjL) showing what it does

Apologies if my explanation is confusing, I am confusing myself a bit :-)
Any help or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the lines in this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addLabel_Item', function () {
    var $li = $(this).closest('.listed');

    $("#list_reference_2").show();
    $li.after($("#list_reference_2").clone().removeAttr('id'));
    $("#list_reference_2").hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tx7hbkjL/15/

PS: Take a look at your duplicate IDs, like #addLabel_Item. IDs must be unique in the page, use class instead.

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. Will up vote soon as I have my reputation up (new to SOF).

Comment: Muito bem, obrigado :-)

Comment: I have updated the code, however once there are nested items generated, clicking to add lines results in two lines (the correct one + another) being added when clicking any button. Any suggestions? I have updated the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jamesstern/tx7hbkjL/9/ to show the issue. Thank you

Comment: You mean the last line? It's the #list_reference_2, which was shown in the click function. You can hide it after the clone. See my update. :)

Comment: Apologies, I posted the wrong link. The correct one is : http://jsfiddle.net/jamesstern/tx7hbkjL/13/ . I have tried hiding the element after cloning.

Comment: I think you only have to change .parents() to .closest() and it'll work, because you have two parents with the class .listed. See my update.

Comment: Thank you so much once again Everton, that looks like it did the trick.